# why does `git branch -a` not show branches from `git branch -r`?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

When I do `git branch -r`  I see the following:

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  origin/<other-branch>
```

But when I do `git branch -a` I see the following:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/<other-branch>
```

Why is it that I don't see the branches listed from `git branch -r` as well?  Is the `remotes/`  removed from the path name when you do `git branch -r` because they are all remote?  mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. :)

With `-r` only remote-tracking branches are shown. With `-a` both remote-tracking and local branches are shown. Because you have only one local branch (master). This branch is the only difference in your outputs.

And yes. With `-a` remote-tracking branches are explicitly marked as remote, while with `-r` it is already clear that those are remote branches.